# Rsyslog send a message programmatically

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

How to send a message to `rsyslog` deamon programmatically (from a custom program)? 
In the `syslog` there are `openlog`...`syslog`...`closelog` functions available. But how can i do it in case of `rsyslog`?

Comment: rsyslogd is a compatible replacement for syslogd. You can use the same functions to write messages, without regard to what daemon is going to read them.

Answer (score 0):

rsyslog is a central log program.
You could `cat /etc/rsyslog.conf` to watch how your rsyslog is configured. 
Default configuration use imuxsock and imjournal.

imuxsock module actually listen like /dev/log or /run/systemd/journal/syslog. This means you could use syslog(3) `man 3 syslog` or cmd `logger 123` to write log into /var/log/messages.

imjournal means rsyslog read log from systemd-journald(/var/log/journal/$(uuid)/*.journal. You could use sd-journal(3) api or journal cmd like `echo 123 | systemd-cat` to write to journal, and then rsyslog read log from it. you can see journal with `journalctl -e` to see the newest journal.